# Add default value to input text not to be deleted when customer fill this field

Tags: javascript, css, html

How to make input text default value not to be deleted, User can only add to default value.

Comment: this question is not clear

Comment: <input  value="default" type="text"> We need the user to append value to it not to delete the default @brk

Comment: Text inputs are either editable or not. So change approach: show the default value before and outside of the text input field, then add the default value to their input string after they submit.

Comment: Can we control it using length?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this Angular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470953/how-to-initialize-a-input-with-a-value-that-cant-be-deleted-but-allow-the-user).

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const DEFAULT_VALUE = input.value;

input.addEventListener('input', checkInput);

function checkInput(e) {
  const currentInput = this.value;
  const currentInputDefaultPart = currentInput.substring(0, DEFAULT_VALUE.length);

  // check if the default part is no longer same as DEFAULT
  if (currentInputDefaultPart !== DEFAULT_VALUE) {
    // reset
    this.value = DEFAULT_VALUE;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Your name: ">
```

[`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is used so the part of the value to compare is the part that has to stay the same.

```
"Your name: Anne".substring(0, DEFAULT_VALUE.length) 
// => "Your name: "
"Your name:".substring(0, DEFAULT_VALUE.length) 
// => "Your name:"
```

Comment: It's not completely perfect, because if you select part of the default text and delete it, the custom part gets deleted, having said that - It's still a nice and sufficient solution of a bad UX :)

Comment: @AlonEitan yeah, was working on that initially but ended discarding it (feeling lazy to explain it in the answer:/ ).